# Chrome MediaRecorder API can not record REMOTE video from FreeSwitch, but local media can be recorded

Tags: html, google-chrome, mediarecorder, freeswitch, jssip

Issue: When we record *remote* video (only) streams in Chrome by using the built-in MediaRecorder API, it returns blob objects; when we merge all blob files with the Blob API and create an object URL, it’s not playable with html5 players.

I’m using jssip on the client side and FreeSwitch on the server side.

Example code:

```
var options = {
    videoBitsPerSecond: 2500000,
    ignoreMutedMedia: true,
    mimeType: 'video/webm'
}
_this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(e.stream, options);
_this.recorder.ondataavailable = function (event) {
    if (event.data.size > 0) {
        chunks.push(event.data);
    }
};
_this.recorder.onstop = function () {
    var superBuffer = new Blob(chunks, {
        type: 'video/webm'
    });

    var url = URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer);
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = 'display: none';
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'test.webm';
    a.click();
}

_this.recorder.start();
```

With that code example we are recording video from a REMOTE stream. Once recording is stopped, we are creating a blob file, which is not playable in Chrome.

The blob file has size and type as expected.

If we change `_this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(e.stream, options)` to `_this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(localMediaStream, options)`, then the file can be recorded and it is playable.

If we play a remote or local stream directly to the video object, then video is playing and there are no problems with that.

The very same code with REMOTE and LOCAL media streams is working very well in FireFox. The problem is only in Chrome.

My `mediaConstraints` is this:

```
mediaConstraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: true
}
```

With those `mediaConstraints`, recording is not working.

But when I change `mediaConstraints` to:

```
mediaConstraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: true
}
```

…then REMOTE video can be recorded and it is playable in Chrome.

Here is the invite SDP body:

```
>     v=0
>     o=- 8064839774906199900 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
>     s=-
>     t=0 0
>     a=group:BUNDLE video
>     a=msid-semantic: WMS mn9jKVP8YQWdoANy4IuThCbAkYDNH6Rn48wy
>     m=video 45331 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 98 100 102 127 97 99 101 125
>     c=IN IP4 x.x.x.x
>     a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
>     a=candidate:2702239670 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.1.103 45331 typ host generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
>     a=candidate:542695682 1 udp 1686052607 x.x.x.x 45331 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.103 rport 45331 generation 0 network-id 2
> network-cost 10
>     a=candidate:4019395398 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.1.103 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
>     a=ice-ufrag:WoJH
>     a=ice-pwd:0plhRV6alFSPYNFZzPeLIQjD
>     a=fingerprint:sha-256 76:74:B1:90:73:A5:7C:AC:1F:D5:F6:99:63:FC:60:6F:07:C0:F6:6A:CB:78:30:A4:19:3E:09:27:F0:EB:04:5E
>     a=setup:actpass
>     a=mid:video
>     a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
>     a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
>     a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
>     a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
>     a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
>     a=sendrecv
>     a=rtcp-mux
>     a=rtcp-rsize
>     a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
>     a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
>     a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
>     a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
>     a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
>     a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
>     a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
>     a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
>     a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
>     a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
>     a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
>     a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
>     a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
>     a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
>     a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
>     a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
>     a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
>     a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
>     a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
>     a=rtpmap:102 red/90000
>     a=rtpmap:127 ulpfec/90000
>     a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
>     a=fmtp:97 apt=96
>     a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
>     a=fmtp:99 apt=98
>     a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
>     a=fmtp:101 apt=100
>     a=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000
>     a=fmtp:125 apt=102
>     a=ssrc-group:FID 2091687367 3809002701
>     a=ssrc:2091687367 cname:6FAXPNxjytcrrFeT
>     a=ssrc:2091687367 msid:mn9jKVP8YQWdoANy4IuThCbAkYDNH6Rn48wy 7369ece0-53c3-44b6-8ada-8fd112f8018b
>     a=ssrc:2091687367 mslabel:mn9jKVP8YQWdoANy4IuThCbAkYDNH6Rn48wy
>     a=ssrc:2091687367 label:7369ece0-53c3-44b6-8ada-8fd112f8018b
>     a=ssrc:3809002701 cname:6FAXPNxjytcrrFeT
>     a=ssrc:3809002701 msid:mn9jKVP8YQWdoANy4IuThCbAkYDNH6Rn48wy 7369ece0-53c3-44b6-8ada-8fd112f8018b
>     a=ssrc:3809002701 mslabel:mn9jKVP8YQWdoANy4IuThCbAkYDNH6Rn48wy
>     a=ssrc:3809002701 label:7369ece0-53c3-44b6-8ada-8fd112f8018b
```

And here is the server response SDP:

```
v=0
o=matrix 1346400881 1346400882 IN IP4 x.x.x.x
s=matrix
c=IN IP4 x.x.x.x
t=0 0
m=video 27194 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
b=AS:1024
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=fingerprint:sha-256 8E:7D:E1:1A:77:BA:97:64:39:B1:41:FC:E5:28:8A:9E:85:EB:FB:DB:A7:57:0F:EF:E6:CA:AF:EE:45:89:47:D5
a=setup:active
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:27194 IN IP4 x.x.x.x
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=ssrc:1346687882 cname:v1aY4xDDn9cbcqMy
a=ssrc:1346687882 msid:NcXTCdxPIZFIYcoKvW2crReVhSijNter v0
a=ssrc:1346687882 mslabel:NcXTCdxPIZFIYcoKvW2crReVhSijNter
a=ssrc:1346687882 label:NcXTCdxPIZFIYcoKvW2crReVhSijNterv0
a=ice-ufrag:dEAumFftnoD1HHi2
a=ice-pwd:yiQtGkWTkZVmgxKj2bEfGKyU
a=candidate:1419127948 1 udp 659136 x.x.x.x 27194 typ host generation 0
a=end-of-candidates
```

What can possibly be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with a similar issue so I think what I discovered might help you.

Chrome doesn't support the `IgnoreMutedMedia` property for `MediaRecorder` so the media recorder is waiting for the audio track to start before it starts recording. You can test this by running a `mediaRecorder.requestData()` to fire the `ondataavailable` event, then look at the value of `event.data.size`:

```
setInterval(function(){
    _this.recorder.requestData(); // request data every second
},1000);

_this.recorder.ondataavailable = function (event) {
    console.log("DATA Size: " + event.data.size) // print data size
    if (event.data.size > 0) {
        chunks.push(event.data);
    }
};
```

So what I had to do was isolate just the video track then create a new MediaStream object with only a video track from the original stream.

```
_this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(new MediaStream(e.stream.getVideoTracks()), options);
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank You very much for information! But this way my recorded videos are still not playable.  If i change from e.remoteStream.getVideoTracks() to localStream, it can be recorded and it is playable. But what i need is to make possible record remote streams :(

Comment: Does the call have audio or is the call video only?

Comment: I mean are you not recording audio because it's not in the call or are you not recording it because of security or some other reason?

Comment: The audio is not in the call. It is a special design of our system where we can not allow audio together with video.

Comment: I think the frame rate gets messed up with out audio. I was able to pipe in a dtmf tone which kick-started the recording. You might need to find a way to pipe in some white noise to get it to record correctly